# Quotation marks not works correctly

Tags: swift

I dont know how I can use this:

```
"\(something)"
```

With this:

```
"\(otherthing)"
```

Like that:

```
 botaoA.setTitle("\(myAnswers[myQuestions.indexOfObject("\(myQuestions.new)")][0])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

But the quotation marks not works corretly..

Comment: Please post what title do you have now and what do you want to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to guess but I think you need

```
botaoA.setTitle("\(myAnswers[myQuestions.indexOfObject(myQuestions.new)][0])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Avt is very correct, but the code is not great to read. My suggestion is that you should separate the elements of your code:

```
let questionIndex = myQuestions.indexOfObject("\(myQuestions.new)")
let selectedAnswer = myAnswers[questionIndex][0]
botaoA.setTitle(selectedAnswer, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```